# Lazy loading list does not refresh in Getx bottomsheet

Tags: flutter, lazy-loading, bottom-sheet, flutter-getx

I have a lazy loading list displayed using getx bottom sheet. The problem is when the list is updated in the controller the bottom sheet does not refresh to show the new updates as expected.

Here is the code I wrote:

**Controller**

```
class LazyListController extends GetxController {

  RxList<String> myList = RxList<String>([]);
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  int currentMax = 10;

  void onInit(){
    super.onInit();
    myList.value = List.generate(10, (i) => "Item : ${i + 1}");
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels >=
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent * 0.8) {
        _getMoreData();
      }
    });
  }

  void _getMoreData() {
    List<String> _list = [];

    for (int i = currentMax; i < currentMax + 10; i++) {
      if (i == currentMax) print('CURRENT MAX: $currentMax');
      _list.add("Item : ${i + 1}");
    }

    myList.value.addAll(_list);

    currentMax = currentMax + 10;
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }

}
```

**View**

```
reviewsListBottomSheet() {
  var controller = Get.find<ReviewController>();

  return Get.bottomSheet(
    return Obx(
      () => Container(
        height: Get.height * 0.90,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8), 
              spreadRadius: 200, 
              blurRadius: 200, 
              offset: Offset(0, 20),
            ),
          ],
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
            topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'List of Items',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
               ],
            ),
            const Divider(color: Colors.grey),
            const SizedBox(height: 10)(),
            Container(
              height: Get.height * 0.625,
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: controller.scrollController,
                itemCount: controller.myList.length,
                
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(controller.myList[i]),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10)(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    isDismissible: true,
    barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    enableDrag: true,
    isScrollControlled: true,
  );
}
```

Please how can this issue be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just switched to using GetBuilder and the bottomsheet updates.

**Controller**

```
class LazyListController extends GetxController {

  List<String> myList = [];
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  int currentMax = 10;

  void onInit(){
    super.onInit();
    myList = List.generate(10, (i) => "Item : ${i + 1}");
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels >=
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent * 0.8) {
        _getMoreData();
      }
    });
  }

  void _getMoreData() {
    List<String> _list = [];

    for (int i = currentMax; i < currentMax + 10; i++) {
      if (i == currentMax) print('CURRENT MAX: $currentMax');
      _list.add("Item : ${i + 1}");
    }

    myList.addAll(_list);
    
    currentMax = currentMax + 10;
    update();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }

}
```

**View**

```
reviewsListBottomSheet() {
  var controller = Get.find<ReviewController>();

  return Get.bottomSheet(
    GetBuilder<ReviewController>(
        init: controller,
        autoRemove: false,
        builder: (controller) {
          return Container(
            height: Get.height * 0.90,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8), 
                  spreadRadius: 200, 
                  blurRadius: 200, 
                  offset: Offset(0, 20),
                ),
              ],
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'List of Items',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Spacer(),
                  ],
                ),
                const Divider(color: Colors.grey),
                FormLabelGap(),
                Container(
                  height: Get.height * 0.625,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: controller.scrollController,
                    itemCount: controller.myList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(controller.myList[i]),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                 ),
                FormLabelGap(),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }),
    isDismissible: true,
    barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    enableDrag: true,
    isScrollControlled: true,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you're not using `myList` to populate list of items in the `Column` widget. You could do something like:

```
ListView.builder(
 shrinkWrap: true,
 itemCount: controller.myList.length,
 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return Row(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
   children: [
    Text(
     'List Items at $index',
     style: TextStyle(
      color: AppColors.nBlue,
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
     ),
    ),
    const Spacer(),
    FormLabelGap(),
   ],
  ),
 }
)
```

Comment: Sorry about not pasting that part of the code, just added it. The problem is when the list is updated in the controller the bottom sheet does not refresh to show the new update as expected.

Comment: Try using `Getx<ReviewController>` instead of `GetBuilder<ReviewController>` . Although the only widget needing a reactive state is the `ListView.builder` so first try wrapping the `ListView.builder` in `Getx<ReviewController>`